# VBA saved workbooks do not open to the last active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am generating and saving multiple workbooks from another workbook, but when I reopen the saved workbooks the last activated sheet ("Summary") is not active.

I've tried different file formats with the same result. If I pause the code, the Activate command works and if I manually save it from there the Summary sheet is active when opened again. I do not want to save the generated workbooks as macro enabled with an Activate on open.

```
Sub brandSalesReports()
    Set dataWb = ActiveWorkbook
    wbPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Set macroWb = Workbooks("Macros.xlsm")
    macroWb.Activate
    Set brandTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("BrandTable")
    With brandTable.DataBodyRange
        tRows = .Rows.Count
    End With

    dataWb.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Original"
    Sheets("Original").Copy Before:=Worksheets("Original")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Data"

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 29).End(xlUp).Row 'Get Last Row
    Range("AC1").Value = "Brand"
    'Fill brand based on Product value
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Product = Range("AF" & i).Value
        For j = 2 To tRows + 1
            Brand = brandTable.Range.Cells(j, 1).Value
            If Product Like "*" & Brand & "*" Then
                Range("AC" & i).Value = Brand
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastColLetter = Split(Cells(1, LastCol).Address, "$")(1)
    'Create workbooks for each brand
    For k = 2 To tRows + 1
        Brand = brandTable.Range.Cells(k, 1).Value
        For l = 1 To LastRow
            If l = 1 Then
                Set currentWb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
                ActiveSheet.Name = "Data"
                Set SourceRange = dataWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:" & LastColLetter & "1")
                Set DestRange = currentWb.Range("A1:" & LastColLetter & "1")
                DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value
                Row = 2
                dataWb.Activate
            ElseIf Range("B" & l).Value = Brand Then
                Set SourceRange = dataWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & l & ":" & LastColLetter & l)
                Set DestRange = currentWb.Range("A" & Row & ":" & LastColLetter & Row)
                DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value
                Row = Row + 1
            End If
        Next l
        currentWb.Activate
        Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets("Data")).Name = "Summary" 'Add new sheet
        LastPivotRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If LastPivotRow <> 1 Then
            'PIVOT TABLE CODE HERE, ALL WORKS
            Sheets("Summary").Activate
            Name = Brand & " Sales Report - " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy")
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            currentWb.SaveAs Filename:=wbPath & "\" & Name, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        End If
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next k
    dataWb.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you should try to break your code apart into more well-defined blocks if you can.

Having a sub dedicated to building brand labels, a sub dedicated to creating new workbooks, a sub for writing the pivot tables, one for saving each workbook, and so on will make it easier to debug your code.

I specifically suggest this because breaking up your code into smaller subroutines can let you test less code at once. Therefore you will be able to determine if the issue in your code lies within a specific block, or how those blocks are being chained together (implementation bug vs. integration bug). If you know which block, (or combination of blocks) are causing your issue you can approach debugging in a more targeted manner.

Anyways, looking at your code you are using lots of implicit references. (ex: `Range("AC1").Value = "Brand"`) I would instead urge you to use explicit references (ex: `dataWb.Sheets("data").Range("AC1").Value = "Brand"`). This is because implicit references are chosen by the computer at runtime, and are not always what you expect them to be. By explicitly stating to use "X" workbook's sheet "Y" we avoid referencing the wrong workbook/worksheet/table/etc.

As an argument to use explicit references, try this minimal example, which correctly saves a file with a summary sheet, and additionally correctly opens to the "summary" sheet.

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add()
    wb.Activate
    wb.Worksheets.Add(Before:=wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")).Name = "Summary"
    wb.Sheets("Summary").Activate
    wb.SaveAs "Test"
    wb.Close (False)
End Sub
```

If changing your references to be explicit does not solve your issue, I suspect this might be something with your application state. Have you frozen the application before running macros or done anything else?